# Стримминг RTSP видео с кодеком на андроид

Tags: android, videoview, камера, rtsp, кодек

Есть камера, которая передает видео по RTSP протоколу, но с кодеком. Кодек на выбор:MPEG4,H.264,MJPEG. Нужно реализовать эту передачу под андроид, видео передается по локалке - передаю rtsp://ip/дальше путь, VLC может воспроизвести, с любым кодеком, пробовал. А вот андроид нет, делаю через VideoView, не знаю как можно это реализовать. Что делать с кодеком?